# self.fp = open(self.filename, '%sb' % omode) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Field found

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to run a python code to post-process netcdf data, and calling a function i get the error:     self.fp = open(self.filename, '%sb' % omode)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Field found

I put the function and the part of the code which calls it. Someone can tell me how to solve the problem?? I suppose it is a very stupid one, but i cannot find a way to solve it because the file that I have to open is a netcdf file which uses a class to read the file itself.

```
class DataFieldForOHstarSimulation(object):

def __init__(self, solution_file, grid_file, use_precomputed_values=True):
    # open the solution file
    self.solution_netcdf_file = sp.io.netcdf.netcdf_file(solution_file)
    # create shortcut to vars
    self.vars = self.solution_netcdf_file.vars

# open the grid file
self.grid_netcdf_file = sp.io.netcdf.netcdf_file(grid_file)

# make shortcut to points; assign empty array
self.pnt = np.empty((3, 

self.grid_netcdf_file.dimensions["no_of_points"]))
    # asign coordinates to points, convert to metres
    self.pnt[:] = self.grid_netcdf_file.variables['points_xc'][:]*0.001, \
                  self.grid_netcdf_file.variables['points_yc'][:]*0.001, \
                  self.grid_netcdf_file.variables['points_zc'][:]*0.001
        # save the physical limits of the data
        self.extents = np.vstack([np.min(self.pnt, axis=1),
                                  np.max(self.pnt, axis=1)])

        # build the KDTree to access points close to the arbitrary point
        self.tree = sp.spatial.cKDTree(self.pnt.T, leafsize=120)

        # do we want to compute spectra for every point or use the
        # approximations from the pre-computed intrpolators
        self.use_precomputed_values = use_precomputed_values

        # calculate the refractive index for each point
        self.refractiveIndex()


# create solution field object
solutionField = Field(solution_file)

# create grid object
grid = Grid(grid_file)

# create main data field object
dataField = DataFieldForOHstarSimulation(solutionField,grid, use_precomputed_values=use_precomputed_values)
```

And then I get the error:

```
self.fp = open(self.filename, '%sb' % omode)
```

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Field found

Comment: You need to also include the code where you set `self.filename` in the first place

Comment: At the beginning of the code i have solution file defined, as it follows: solution_file = "myfille"

Comment: @NickMartin unfortunately I had also to include files and some other function to calculate spectra, so it is quite impossible to post something reproducilble :(

Comment: @Migwell that's why I don't understand... I cannot open the file as a string because I need to read variables form the file which is a netcdf file...

Comment: You should search around the site for definition of a MCVE. In doing so, your question may end up not being needed to be asked.

Comment: @LoneWanderer I know that the example should be reproducible, but i cannot attach the data being a cfd simulation using classes form a kit of other files... so I should put more or less everything that I have here. I try to explain the problem a bit better. so maybe you can better understand what it's wrong eventually. I have a netcdf file that I have to open to read in the variables with a class named Field. I pass my solution file to the new class I created DataFieldForOHstarSimulation, but it says that this class want only a string or buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, there was an error in calling the file as a netcdf instead of as a string. Anyway, thanks for the support to my first question!!